# Resolving NUnit "No suitable constructor was found" message

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5

I have a unit test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeClassIntegrationTests : SomeClass
```

With public constructor:

```
public SomeClassIntegrationTests (ILogger l) : base(l)
{
}
```

When I attempt to run the test I get "No suitable constructor was found" error.

I tried changing the `TestFixture` attribute to `[TestFixture(typeof(ILogger))]` but it results in the same error message not allowing me to run or debug the test.

Any idea how to modify the `TestFixture` attribute to get the test to run or resolve this issue in some other way?

Comment: For `[TestFixture(typeof(ILogger))]`to work, you would need a constructor `SomeClassIntegrationTests(Type)`.

Comment: @KlausGütter That is not a valid constructor given that SomeClassIntegrationTests inherits from SomeClass.

Comment: I ended up creating a parameterless constructors in the base class and the test class which resolved the "no suitable constructor found" issue but I'll leave the question open in case someone knows how TestFixture attribute should be modified in this scenario.

Comment: You can't. Attribute parameters must be constants of one of these types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort, System.Type, enum, arrays of these types. There is no way to specify an ILogger as attribute parameter. See my answer for possible alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probable need an instance of a class implementing ILogger.

Option 1: use null (if the logger is not really required):

```
[TestFixture(null)]
```

Option 2: use always the same concrete class (or a mock): add a parameterless constructor

```
SomeClassIntegrationTests()
: this(new MyLogger())
{
}
```

and

```
[TestFixture]
```

Option 3: you may want to test with different loggers

```
SomeClassIntegrationTests(Type t)
: this((Ilogger)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
{
}
```

and

```
[TestFixture(typeof(MyLogger))]
```